# Tomcat starts but greenstone homepage and localhost are not showing

Tags: tomcat, localhost

Tomcat starts but the home page cannot open with URL:

`http://localhost:8383/greenstone3`

Tomcat is available in packages in greenstone folder. (`Greenstone Digital Library software version 3.08`).

It seems Tomcat was started in log files. 
But why not opening `localhost`?
Pl help

Comment: Do see anything in `catalina.out` log file? Where can I grab the war file of greenstone?

Comment: yes, rishikesh.. ---Do see anything in catalina.out log file? ---- pls read catalina output "/usr/local/Greenstone3/installed/packages/tomcat/bin/catalina.sh: /opt/java/jre1.8.0_74/bin/java: /lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory". what does it means?... can you help to solve this problem? ----Where can I grab the war file of greenstone?---For installing Greenstone DL software, pl see http://www.greenstone.org/download

Comment: have u tried that?

Comment: sorry, i didn't tried anything on greenstone.